# Splitting group of arrays into multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array group such as below:

```
array1=[array([[-9.22122598e-02, -7.77119026e-02,  2.33460721e-02, ...,
          1.34549016e-04, -1.88019443e-02,  7.18783448e-03],
        [-1.46948949e-01, -1.48228452e-01, -1.14444084e-01, ...,
         -2.28411201e-02, -5.35020716e-02, -1.63860857e-01],
        [-7.87959695e-02, -4.09973189e-02,  4.28187810e-02, ...,
          9.49193258e-03, -1.08401831e-02, -2.98883356e-02],
        ...,
        [-7.80879855e-02, -1.07460372e-01,  6.62480742e-02, ...,
         -8.09924379e-02,  5.38539886e-02,  2.43474636e-02],
        [-3.96090448e-02,  1.65226907e-02, -1.54950283e-02, ...,
          9.37677100e-02,  6.74941950e-03, -9.88303050e-02],
        [-3.74811813e-02, -3.71974520e-02,  8.63581598e-02, ...,
          4.89948802e-02, -2.88915746e-02, -2.82045268e-02]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-0.2272577 , -0.19350286,  0.01672136, ..., -0.07294147,
          0.03613289, -0.04197036],
        [-0.17333736, -0.06534146, -0.00429066, ..., -0.00380382,
         -0.00685734, -0.03633693],
        [-0.1075289 , -0.06630006,  0.01478036, ...,  0.03524185,
         -0.04992134,  0.00623439],
        ...,
        [-0.10894527,  0.06168704,  0.05745631, ..., -0.1480621 ,
          0.30109984, -0.07781448],
        [-0.06979708, -0.08451148,  0.01770407, ...,  0.02398864,
          0.01148526, -0.02312317],
        [-0.0112561 , -0.04406631,  0.01535748, ..., -0.00543236,
          0.05647333,  0.02899001]], dtype=float32), dtype=float32)]
```

`len(array1)` gives me 2.
I want to split them into single ones. then I tried the below code to split them:

```
array2 = []
for x in array:
    a = np.array_split(x, len(x))
    array2.append(a)
```

but it still gives me `len(array2)` is 2
and the result of array2 is:

```
[[array([[-0.09221226, -0.0777119 ,  0.02334607, ...,  0.00013455,
          -0.01880194,  0.00718783]], dtype=float32),
...,
array([[-2.7057607e-02, -4.5802284e-02,  3.7913073e-02, ...,
           2.9074477e-02, -2.2583639e-02, -5.5410979e-05]], dtype=float32),
array([[ 0.0220767 ,  0.00741114, -0.02423782, ..., -0.00413209,
          -0.04292217,  0.01013315]], dtype=float32),
  array([[-0.08061106, -0.043897  ,  0.02898987, ...,  0.0409692 ,
          -0.0795244 ,  0.01140197]], dtype=float32),
...,
array([[-2.7057607e-02, -4.5802284e-02,  3.7913073e-02, ...,
           2.9074477e-02, -2.2583639e-02, -5.5410979e-05]], dtype=float32),
...,
array([[-0.04212699, -0.04942814,  0.04590566, ...,  0.02718335,
          -0.00644397, -0.02039399]], dtype=float32),
array([[-0.0017318 , -0.05600583,  0.00459289, ...,  0.02742467,
          -0.01076222, -0.01778808]], dtype=float32)]]
```

Can you advise on how to split them correctly?

Comment: Take a look at [numpy.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

Comment: `first_array = array1[0]`
`second_array = array1[1]`

Comment: @HenrikBo Nah you took the question in the wrong way, OP wants an array of single elements array if I understand well. 

@Muugii Can you add an example of what you want, so that it's clear to everyone ? Also, IMO you should try at first with smaller arrays with easier values. My guess is that `array1` contains multiple levels of arrays, making it less evident to flatten, however I don't know much of numpy

Comment: `array1` is a **list** with 2 elements   `array2` is a list with 2 elements.  That should be obvious from the iteration. Each of those elements is now a list of arrays,  the result of splitting each of the original arrays.  The shapes in `array2` are (1,n).

Comment: @Nei, you count 'levels' in arrays as you would with lists, by the nesting of brackets.  He starts with a list of 2 arrays.  The result is a list of 2 lists - each containing multiple (1,n) shaped arrays.  The OP's "single ones" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Please make a minimal example with arrays of 3 or 4 elements to make it clear what you want. Right now you have a list of two arrays. I don't think you want to split them, but I could be wrong. Try `np.concatenate(array1, axis=0)` or something like that and see if if fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that your problem is with `len(array1) == 2`, I suspect that you are thinking about this backwards. First of all `array1` is not a numpy array. It is a python list with two arrays as its elements. You probably want to make it into an array with all the elements combined:

```
array1 = np.concatenate(array1, axis=0)
```

Now `array1` is an actual numpy array with all the rows in the original two combined. `len(array1)` will now give the same result that `len(array1[0]) + len(array1[1])` would have given you before.